# Not able to see Google+ API data and API details when using google as social account provider in django-all-auth

Tags: django, google-api, django-allauth

We are using google as social provider with below configuration in a django website:

```
django-allauth==0.23.0

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
  'google':
    { 'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
      'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' }
    }}
```

Credentials are created in API Manager in Google developer console. We are able to login to website using google. But, 
there is no data (Quota, Traffic etc.) visible in google developer console for this Google+ API.

[image]